# Sublime text 2 search does not work

Tags: sublimetext2

I have ST2 installed on Win7 and for some reason the global 'Find in Files' (ctrl+shift+f) stopped working (it worked before). Now all i get is :

> Searching 0 files for "capbSectionac"
>
> 0 matches across 0 files

The regular search in the currently opened file is working correctly.

I tried re-installing it but to no avail :(

Anyone encountered it? Any solution?

Comment: Did your method of reinstallation entail [reverting to a freshly installed state](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert)? Do you have any non-vanilla packages installed?

Comment: @ProtractorNinja - The link you posted is dead

Comment: Oops! I somehow managed to lose the `.html` off of the end of the link. Sorry about that! [This one should work](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert.html).

Comment: @ProtractorNinja - yeah, i did it and still no good :(

Answer (score 5):

Note that it says "Searching 0 files".

In the second field "Where:", make sure you don't have a folder selected. You should see the placeholder text "Open files and folders" which means that it will search in the whole project. If you don't see this placeholder, even if the "Where" field is empty try clicking on the "..." button and then click on "Clear".

source: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12611

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. At some time I noticed that the `Where:` field (below `Find:`) didn't show any placeholder text ("Open files and folders"), as it is supposed to when it's empty. It turns out that the `Where:` field wasn't empty and therefore the search was like happening nowhere. As I cleared this field, the search worked again.

Comment: This was my problem despite how old this post is. In the `Where:` field select all and delete, then add an include, exclude etc. Fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

Press ctrl F . then in left side of search bar, enable Wrap. with inverted reload sign

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Sublime Text 3, so when I first tried to use Find In Files (shift+command+y) it yielded nothing but 0 search results.

I brought up Find (command + f) and I noticed alot of spaces before my search term.

I cleared out those extra spaces and left my search term.  Brough back up Find In Files and the search worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

I keep having this problem in Unbuntu. The solution I found was just to delete the folder

```
/home/<user>/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/Package Control.cache
```

I think this happens because I have file synchronization on save but can't be sure.

Comment: Tried it, didn't help :(

Comment: Not helping for me either.

Comment: I've actually stopped having this problem since I upgraded to sublime 3. Sublime 3 brought new problems. :(